# Bash assigning tail value to a variable

Tags: linux, bash, unix, variables, tail

Trying to create a workflow with a "output" file that updates from time to time.

```
    #!/bin/bash

echo "start flow"

tail -n output.txt
```

So when the last line of "output.txt" is created, then it should be a variable, something like this:

Lets say that the last line in "output.txt" is a youtubelink. (for example)
then the code should be something like:

```
firefox $'the_last_line_in_output.txt'
```

Dont really know how to do this so if anyone could help me that would be awesome :)

/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subshell substitution:

```
firefox $(tail -1 output.txt)
```